# StreamListener with Tweepy, TypeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to recover tweets from specific hastags. I'm using Python 2.7.6 and Tweepy to listen to an hastag. Following this article :  [Introduction to tweepy, Twitter for Python](http://pythoncentral.io/introduction-to-tweepy-twitter-for-python/) I end up with :

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

consumer_secret = ""
consumer_key = ""


class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        # Prints the text of the tweet
        print('Tweet text: ' + status.text)


        return true

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print('Got an error with status code: ' + str(status_code))
        return True # To continue listening

    def on_timeout(self):
        print('Timeout...')
        return True # To continue listening

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    stream = Stream(auth, listener)
    stream.filter(track=['#apple'])
```

But when I run the script, I have the following error :

> File "test.py", line 40, in 
>       stream.filter(track=['#apple'])
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 430, in filter
>       self._start(async)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 346, in _start
>       self._run()
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 286, in _run
>       raise exception
>   TypeError: cannot make memory view because object does not have the buffer interface

Does anyone have an idea why ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be a known issue [#659](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/659).

If you downgrade `requests` to 2.7 should fix the issue.

```
pip uninstall requests
pip install requests==2.7
```